# Run Eclipse project from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I am having two problems regarding compiling and running an Eclipse java project from command line. This works fine when I am just running from the eclipse IDE. I tried googling but couldn't really get the thing working. Any help is much appreciated.

Problem 1: When I try to compile from a location different from the directory where the .java file is, it throws the error "**cannot read: myfile.java**". But if I migrate to this directory then it compiles.
The command that I was giving is (when in some other directory):
*javac -cp C:\ABC\src\XYZ myfile.java*
The command that I was giving when in XYZ directory:
*javac myfile.java*
This generated two .class files myfile.class and Testing_Thread.class(I guess this because I have a thread in my code)

Problem 2: After I have compiled by going to its directory, when I try to run the program, I get the error "**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myfile (wrong name: XYZ/myfile.java)**" even when I am trying to run from the XYZ directory. I get the same error when I try to run from some other place also.
The command that I was giving when in XYZ directory:
*java myfile*
The command that I was giving when in some other place:
*java -cp C:\ABC\src\XYZ myfile*

I am also attaching a hierarchy of my directory structure if it is of any help:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These examples assume the following source structure:

```
C:\temp\compile-test\src\a\b\c\D.java
```

Where D.java is:

```
package a.b.c;

public class D { }
```

The first problem, **cannot read: myfile.java**, is because it is not correct to use the **`cp`** command line option to point to your source code.

```
C:\temp\compile-test\src>javac -cp c:\temp\compile-test\src\a\b\c D.java
javac: file not found: D.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

This should instead be the following, where `javac` is run from your source folder, and we can use relative paths to the source files (NOTE - `javac` is run from the source folder here):

```
C:\temp\compile-test\src>javac a\b\c\D.java
```

Or this, where we specify full paths to the source files, and `javac` can be run from anywhere (NOTE - `javac` is run from `C:\` here):

```
C:\>javac temp\compile-test\src\a\b\c\D.java
```

Both of the above options will result in your class files being created in the same folder as the source. I.e.:

```
C:\temp\compile-test\src\a\b\c\D.class
```

For the second problem, if you try and run a class that has a package name from 'inside' the package, this will result in the name being wrong (NOTE - `java` being run from 'inside' the package here):

```
C:\temp\compile-test\src\a\b\c>java D
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: D (wrong name: a/b/c/D)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: D.  Program will exit.
```

To run the `D` class, you should be at the package 'root', and supply the [Fully Qualified Class Name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29). I.e.:

```
C:\temp\compile-test\src>java a.b.c.D
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Note I get an exception as the `D` class doesn't have a main method, and so cannot be run. To fix, we add a main method:

```
package a.b.c;

public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main");
    }
}
```

and re-run:

```
C:\temp\compile-test\src>java a.b.c.D
main
```