# How to run java eclipse project from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, command-line

I'm using a mac, and I'm trying to run a java project created in Eclipse from the command line. My project folder has a bin and src folder, each of which have folders game and display corresponding to packages. There are .java files in `src/*/` and .class files in `bin/*/`

**Here's what worked:**
I compiled everything using `javac src/*/*.java`. I ran my project by going to the src folder (`cd src`) and using `java game.Gomoku` following the [directions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12964654/5565524). Everything worked. The only problem was that now I had a bunch of .class files in my src folder, and I wanted them in my bin folder like Eclipse organized it.

**The problem:**
I figured out that I could do this with `javac -d bin src/*/*.java`. But then when I try `java bin/game/Gomoku` or `java game/Gomoku` or `java -cp bin bin/game/Gomoku` I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class bin.game.Gomoku`. How can I run my project?

Answer (score 2):

So while I was typing my question I came across a solution. After going to bin (`cd bin`) I could run my project with `java game.Gomoku`. I also found that my question had been previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494109/run-eclipse-project-from-command-line), but I'll post this anyways just in case my method for compiling (in my question) can help anyone.